# angular for each with closure scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code

```
$scope.getBooksByUser = function (user) {
    var books = [];
    ProductFactory.getBooks.query({ id: user.id }).$promise.then(function (result) {
        angular.forEach(result, function(i) {
            books.push(i.name);
            debugger;
        })
    });
};
```

As you can see, I am trying to fill a simple javascript array in **angular for each**. When this function is executed, an array `books` is still empty.

I am little confused with this behavior, cause when i try to debug my code i can see that on each iteration value is set in array. Actually chrome debugger shows me that an array `books` is in `closure scope` and i guess that is a reason but i still cant find an explanation and how i can fix it.

Actually if i was using `$scope.books = []` it would be work fine, but i dont need `$scope`, but i need just a javascript array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to post the code for your "ProductFactory" as it may be that your Factory may have an error but the small snippet of code you provided may not be sufficient to diagnose your issue.

Comment: You're pushing `i.name` into `users` array and not to `books` array. That's why it's empty.

Comment: Jesse, no, it works fine i know it, as i said if i would use $scope variable it will be fine

Comment: AWolf, sorry=) it was a typo, i've just edited it

Comment: "i can see that on each iteration value is set in array" - But you also say it's empty. So it's both empty and not empty?

Comment: zeroflagL during debugging i see that step by step values are setting to array, but when for each is finished array books is empty, magic=)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is happening because of `asynchronous` call of `AJAX`. In your case compiler will not wait for your ajax response. You should do it like

```
 ProductFactory.getBooks.query({ id: user.id }).$promise.success(function (result) {
        angular.forEach(result, function(i) {
            books.push(i.name);
            debugger;
        })
    });
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Vineet, thanks you but it doesn't work at all. I get an error in console - 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' pointing to success function